# delete same tag node in an xml object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

for example i want to delete all price tag and their contents.

```
var xml:XML = <breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<description>
two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$7.95</price>
<description>
light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$8.95</price>
<description>
light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream
</description>
<calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>French Toast</name>
<price>$4.50</price>
<description>
thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
</description>
<calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
<name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
<price>$6.95</price>
<description>
two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns
</description>
<calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

i use delete xml..price ,didn't work, the delete operation only works on the first level, i want to delete the tags from the whole tree, is there some easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in one line using filter expression:

```
xml..price.( delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()] );
```

---

To remove all node by a name parameter you can make a function like this:

```
function deleteAllTag(xml:XML, tag:String):void{
 xml.descendants(tag).(delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()] );
}
```

and then:

```
deleteAllTag(xml, "price");
```

Live example at wonderfl : http://wonderfl.net/c/cHfy

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that [deleting XML nodes in as3 is harder than it looks](http://bottomupflash.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/deleting-xml-nodes-harder-than-it-looks/). That article covers the basics of it quite well. You basically need to loop through all nodes and `delete` them one by one, using **array syntax**.

In your case:

```
//to select all price nodes:
trace( "—- xml..price —-" );
trace( xml..price );

trace( "—- delete in loop —-" );

//loop
for each (var price:XML in xml..price)
{
  //and delete each node!
  delete xml..price[0];
}

trace( "—- after delete —-" );
trace(xml);
```

And the ouput is:

```
—- xml..price —-
<price>$5.95</price>
<price>$7.95</price>
<price>$8.95</price>
<price>$4.50</price>
<price>$6.95</price>

—- delete in loop —-

—- after delete —-

<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    <calories>600</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
    <calories>950</calories>
  </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: use this only delete price,can you write a function to do this ?I use xml..[tagName] ,but flash can't compile, and each time use  delete xml..price[0] isn't a good way ,i think.